# Matlab -> Arduino Serial commnication

Tags: matlab, arduino, serial-port, serial-communication

I'm trying to send some data from Matlab to Arduino,but I'm not receiving what I expect, when I send a '5' in a double-variable, I receive the character 'e' at the Arduino Terminal.

The Arduino code is:

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
    {
        if (Serial.available())
        {
           Serial.write(Serial.read());
        }
}
```

And the matlab code is:

```
data=5
PS=serial('COM11','BaudRate',9600);

fopen(PS);

fwrite(PS,data)

fclose(PS);
delete(PS);
clear PS;
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`fprintf`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/serial.fprintf.html) instead? Your `5` will not be sent as string but as binary data, see [`fwrite`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/serial.fwrite.html). I think Arduino works on strings, doesn't it? `fwrite` allows you to set a `'precision'` this may also help if you use it as binary in the Arduino code.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>       Serial.write(Serial.read());
> ```

this sends back exactly what you receive, so it's not really helpful to find out what you received.

- Do you have the possibility to send it somewhere else ? 
  Serial1, Softserial, lcd ?
- Serial.read() returns an int, so you might use Serial.println(Serial.read()) 
   to see the code of what you got
- ... and the number of bytes you received
- sending/reveiving text instead of binary sometimes makes life easier